# C : Can I Snprintf(buffer,buffersize,buffer,..)?

Tags: c, printf, buffer

I got one big structure that is hosting my "html pages" like that :

```
char * HTML_PAGES_ARRAY[n];
```

which I fill with for example a page like :

```
HTML_PAGES_ARRAY[0] = "<h1> Hello %s <h/1>\0"
```

Now, in my child program, I'm calling a function that has to send an array back to the main program to be able to send the array back to the client.

So I have to simulate streaming because all my html page might not fit in the array. Also, as you saw, I want the html page to be customized with variadic arguments.

I want to allocate as less memory possible as I can. (embedded device)

Here's what I came up with

```
        #define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 2000         
        char* str= malloc(sizeof(DEFAULT_BUFLEN));
        memset(str, '\0', sizeof(DEFAULT_BUFLEN));
        snprintf(str, strlen(HTML_PAGES_ARRAY[0]), HTML_PAGES_ARRAY[0], value1);

        //answer being the first buffer I talked about, simulating streaming, to send it back to the main program
        strcpy(answer, str+(*count-1)*(answerSize-1));
        //count being a parameter (an integer to parse my html page), answerSize being the size of my stream buffer answer also placed as parameter
```

It actually works fine but I do not want to allocate that str buffer.

Is there any way to not do that & instead use `snprintf` wuth the same buffer (for example : `snprintf(buffer,buffersize,buffer,...)`) ?

Or maybe any other ideas?

Comment: *C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are **undefined** if a call to sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), or vsnprintf() would cause copying to take place between objects that overlap (e.g., if the target string array and one of the supplied input arguments refer to the same buffer)* - from [man snprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)

Comment: @EugeneSh. right, I knew I read that somewhere. Is there any way to not allocate memory ?

Comment: I have trouble understanding you problem, other than the part I addressed :)

Comment: Why do you need to reformat the string in memory?  If you're writing a web server, can you use `fprintf`, to a FILE pointer connected to the network stream you're serving on?

Comment: Just trying to explore every ways possible about "how can I fill my HTML_PAGE with variadic argument without doing too much memory stuff"

Comment: @SteveSummit I currently have a FS linked to my web server, so I could write to a file & place it there so I can just use my function that gets all the files from the FS right ?

Comment: Would you be happier just allocating your temporary string on the stack instead of on the heap?

Comment: It's not about me being happier @ChristianGibbons . It's about understanding what's the optimal way to achieve my goal

Comment: @JulesA You could write it to a file, yes, and that might be an appropriate way of doing it.  But what I was thinking of was literally fprintfing it to a network stream.  (If you're writing a web server I assume you have network streams you're sending HTML pages to.)

Comment: @SteveSummit this is what I'm doing when I said "I send it back to the main program that sends it to the client" . My problem was that I had variadic elements that I had to fill . But thanks anyways for the idea I did not think about !

Comment: regarding: `<h1> Hello %s <h/1>\0"`  this is not a valid HTML statement.  Perhaps you meant: `<h1> Hello %s </h1>\0"`

Comment: OT:  When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `reallco`  alway check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @user3629249 typo mistake but thanks. That's true I missed that important part !